# is it possible to create XML output with TYPO3 fluid

Tags: xml, typo3, fluid

I want to create an xml output of a database table. the typoscript says the following

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0
    config {
        no_cache = 1
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        disablePrefixComment = 1
        metaCharset = utf-8
        additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
    }
    wrap = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>|</root>
}
```

The fluid template of my plugin says

```
<f:for each="{xmlexports}" as="xmlexport">
    <title>{xmlexport.title}</title>
</f:for>
```

The output code looks like this: [image]

Comment: The extension `news` is outputting XML as well. Maybe take a look how it's done there. https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news/

Comment: You do not have given any information about how you include/call the Fluid-template. So we can just guess a solution... If it's called in an (own) extension, you could set `$this->request->setFormat('xml');`in your controller. If you are including the Fluid-template as a cObject in your TypoScript, you can set `format` in the TS (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#format),... It depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.
There was a stupid error in my root template, I forgot f:format.html

```
<f:format.html>{content}</f:format.html>
```

my full working typoscript setup is

```
  page = PAGE
  page {
    typeNum = 0
    config {
        no_cache = 1
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        disablePrefixComment = 1
        metaCharset = utf-8
        additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
    }
    wrap = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  standalone="yes"?><root>|</root>
}

page.10.format = xml

page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    template = FILE
    template.file = typo3conf/ext/myExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/root.html
    
}
page.10.variables.content < styles.content.get
```

In my case $this->request->setFormat('xml'); was not necessary in the extension controller